# A gentleman is simply a patient wolf

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

[Spirit Animal Meanings: Fox, Owl, Wolf, Bear and Hawk](http://www.gaiamtv.com/article/meaning-behind-your-spirit-animal)

[image]

In this picture with the words *"A gentlemen is simply a patient wolf."*, I can't decide what the animal "wolf" refers. I also found a link mentioned above.
Can I follow it? Let me know your points of views.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: We can offer literal paraphrases of poetic and metaphorical language when the syntax is obscure or difficult, but interpretation of the metaphors themselves is off-topic.

Answer (score 4):

*Wolf* is not being used in a "spirit animal" sense here. Instead, it's figurative, much like when a man is called a dog or a pig when he cheats on his partner. We have the following:

> - [gentleman](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gentleman)
>     1 c (2): a man whose conduct conforms to a high standard of propriety or correct behavior
> - [wolf](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/wolf)
>     1 Used figuratively to refer to a rapacious, ferocious, or voracious person or thing

Basically the message is saying that there's no such thing as a gentleman. They are just fierce, success-hungry people who can be patient in order to achieve their goals. I reason that the message is about achieving goals because it seems to come from a source that promotes motivational memes ("Entrepreneur Motivation").

Comment: This is a good answer except that I think it should mention the "A gentlem**e**n" in the picture is a little different from the "a gentlem**a**n" in your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Wolves are stereotypically known for being

- hunters (actively searching for things to conquer or fight)
- predators (preying on the weak)
- opportunistic (taking advantage of a situation if it benefits oneself)

and the text is saying gentlemen are really the above, but simply more patient.